# Running several update stored procedures in C# code

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a REST WCF service that depend on what pass to the update method it is going to update that column. For example they can update addresses, phone numbers, emails,...

Each of these updates run its own stored procedure to update. I am not sure if my code is ok for this as some problem happened when 2 users try to update their email address at exact same time, so it updates second user email address to 1st user.

```
public Model.ReturnResponse UpdateCustomerProfile(Model.Customer CustomerData)
    {

 Model.Customer customer = GetCustomerInfo.Instance.returnCustomerInfo();
        Model.ReturnResponse rs = new Model.ReturnResponse();


            DAL.DataManager dal = new DAL.DataManager();


                foreach (var pr in CustomerData.GetType().GetProperties())
                {

                    string name = pr.Name;
                    object temp = pr.GetValue(CustomerData, null);


                    if (temp is int)
                    {
                        int value = (int)temp;
                        if (value != 0)
                        {
                            string prName = pr.Name;
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                    if (temp is string)
                    {
                        if (temp != null)
                        {
                            string prName = pr.Name;
                            if (prName == "WORKPHONE")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerPhone(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), "WORK");
                            }
                            if (prName =="HOMEPHONE")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerPhone(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), "HOME");
                            }
                            if (prName =="MOBILEPHONE")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerPhone(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), "MOBILE");
                            }
                            if (prName == "FAXPHONE")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerPhone(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), "FAX");
                            }

                            if (prName == "PRIMARYEMAIL")
                            {

                                   dal.Update_Customer_Email(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), "PRIMARY");
                                }
                            }

                            if (prName == "SECONDARYEMAIL")
                            {
                                                                        dal.Update_Customer_Email(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), "SECONDARY");
                                }
                            }

                            //Mailing Adress
                            if (prName == "MAILINGADDRESSADDRESS_1")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerAddress(customer.Customer_ID, temp.ToString(), null, null, "STR_CP_MAILING");
                            }

                            if (prName == "MAILINGADDRESSADDRESS_2")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerAddress(customer.Customer_ID, null, temp.ToString(), null, null, null,"STR_CP_MAILING");
                            }

                            if (prName == "STR_CP_MAILINGADDRESSCITY")
                            {
                                dal.Update_CustomerAddress(customer.Customer_ID, null, null, temp.ToString(), null, null, "CP_MAILING");
                            }



                        }
                    }
                    if (temp is bool)

                    {
                           string prName = pr.Name;


                           if (prName == "OnlineAgreement")
                           {
                               bool Online_Agreement = dal.Get_Online_Agreement_ByCustomerID(customer.Customer_ID);

                               if (Online_Agreement != Convert.ToBoolean(temp))
                               {

                                   dal.Update_Customer_Online_Agreement(customer.Customer_ID, Convert.ToBoolean(temp));
                               }
                           }
                   }
              }
      }
```

Comment: Please format your code!! It's barely readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only ever updates the Customer_ID obtained from GetCustomerInfo.Instance.returnCustomerInfo(), as opposed to using the Customer_ID passed from CustomerData in the parameter.  How does "GetCustomerInfo.Instance.returnCustomerInfo()" know to get the customer that matches what is passed?  It looks like your code will always only update the same user, regardless of what user information is passed to the routine.

Comment: GetCustomerInfo.Instance.returnCustomerInfo returns correct customer as it get some other info from input (like username, password) to match which user is coming in .